# Replace a DIV with another using effect and set cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, html

I've got some complicated requirements and wondered if there's a way to accomplish this via jQuery:

1. User comes to a web page for the first time today and we show DIV_1.
2. After 30 seconds, we dissolve DIV_1 to DIV_2.
3. We set a cookie on the user's machine that expires when s/he returns tomorrow.
4. If the same user returns today, we only show DIV_2.
5. Tomorrow, we repeat the process: The user will see DIV_1 and then it dissolves to DIV_2.

How do you accomplish this via jQuery? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

```
$(function(){
     if(!$.cookie('repeatVisitor')){
         $.cookie("repeatVisitor", "true", { expires: 1 }); //expires in 1 day
         setTimeout('showDivTwo();', 30000);    
     }
})

function showDivTwo(){
    $('#divOne').fadeOut();
    $('#divTwo').fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri. Wow! You make it looks so easy :)

Comment: A followup: If DIV_2 is to replace DIV_1, do you set its STYLE to display:none? It's not working for me right now.

Comment: The correct call to the setTimeout is this: setTimeout('showDivTwo()', 30000);

Comment: Sorry, I will edit in the setTimeout :) fadeOut will take care of setting display none.